# Which cameras support DNG natively?

Tags: raw, file-format, dng

Not all cameras support DNG natively. That is, if you want to process DNG files they need to be converted from the camera's proprietary RAW format to DNG afterwards. So, which cameras support DNG natively?

I'm thinking it would be best to have one answer per camera manufacturer with each answer listing the camera models but I'm open to something better.

Comment: Not really sure this is a relevant topic. I would reword it to be more of a question, rather than a statement. Also, given that DNG is not a true RAW format, its viability as a "raw" format in cameras is kind of moot.

Comment: What's with the downvote? This is a perfectly legitimate question. +1.

Comment: Some Leicas do, but I don't recall details.

Comment: I agree that this is legitimate question. +1.

Comment: I think DNG is a true RAW format. In the case of Pentax, at least, it faithfully records all the raw, untransformed data from the sensor and camera. There is no loss or compromise.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/extend.html#dngcompatible

Comment: @labnut: Except DNG does not account for the specifics of a given camera. If a camera has a slightly different bayer sensor array it's going to not work well with DNG.

Comment: @labnut - I did not know better at the time, but I have found people showing that Pentax PEF and DNG differ. If you Google, it will lead to some forums where differences are discussed. *I have not verified any claims though.*

Comment: @labnut a true RAW format records the direct output of the sensor. DNG doesn't do that. It's no different than using JPEG for storage, except that it (afaik) uses lossless compression.

Comment: Some of the above is not true. DNG is not like JPEG. It is a container format for recording the direct output of the sensor.

Comment: it's still not a native format, the sensor output is at the very least "normalised" to whatever Adobe has decided is "normal" in order for the DNG processing software to be able to read it.

Comment: Why do you care which camaras use Adobe's particular format?  As long as the raw format of a camera is documented enough so you can extract the raw data, it doesn't matter since you can convert from that to any other format.  Adobe hype aside, there is very little advantage to a camera using DNG as their raw format.  For example, my Nikon uses a modified TIF format for the raw data that they call a NEF file.  This has not been a problem.

Comment: there is no such thing as "native file format" for a sensor, sensors do not create files, there is no reason for DNG to be less native than any other format.

Comment: Help me understand the terminology being used here. in particular the word SUPPORT. My understanding is that cameras do not support DNG files, they create their own proprietary raw file that is then converted to a DNG file once the file has been exported out of the camera. So a better wording of question would be , Which camera RAW formats have the ability to be converted to DNG files in post.

Answer (score 21):

## Pentax

#### Medium-format DLSRs

- 645D
- 645Z

#### Full-frame DSLRs

- K-1
- K-1 II

#### APS-C DSLRs

- K-x
- K-r
- K-5
- K-5 II
- K-7
- K-30
- K-50
- K-500
- K-3
- K-3 II
- K-70
- KP
- K10D *(u)*
- K20D *(u)*
- K200D *(u)*
- K2000 *(u)*

#### Mirrorless

- Q *(u)*
- Q10 *(u)*
- Q7 *(u)*
- Q-S1 *(u)*
- K-01

#### Compact cameras

- MX-1

*Models marked with (u) do not support creating compressed DNGs. The older cameras can save compressed Pentax-proprietary PEF raw files that are smaller than the equivalent DNG raw files. The newer (Q-series) cameras do not support PEF files.*

Comment: Note that K-x and K-7 both supported creating compressed DNG's, the older cameras create DNGs that are larger than their PEF alternatives.

Comment: The K-5 also supports compressed DNG.

Answer (score 13):

### Ricoh

- Caplio GX100
- GR Digital
- GR Digital II
- GR Digital IV
- Ricoh GR
- Ricoh GR II
- GX100
- GX200
- GXR

Comment: The GXR also supports DNG

Answer (score 11):

### Adobe

Adobe maintains [a list of cameras supported by Adobe Camera Raw](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/extend.html#dngcompatible). Any camera that has "DNG" in the "Raw image filename extension" column in the tables produces DNG files that can be read by Adobe Camera Raw.

The list consists mainly of Casio, Leica, Pentax, Ricoh and several Samsung cameras. It might be worth checking the page however as more cameras are added and of course confirming with the manufacturer before making a decision.

### neocamera

For a list of current DNG supporting cameras, it is any easy [search](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php) on Neocamera, just select the DNG check box. [Here are the results](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?outputdng=1).

Answer (score 9):

### Casio

- EXILIM EX-FH100
- EXILIM EX-ZR1000
- EXILIM EX-FC300S
- EXILIM EX-ZR700
- EXILIM EX-ZR710
- EXILIM EX-ZR750
- EXILIM EX-ZR800
- EXILIM EX-ZR850
- EX-ZR1100
- EX-ZR1200
- EX-ZR1300
- EX-ZR1500
- EX-ZR3500
- EX-10
- EX-100
- EX-100F
- EX-100PRO
- EX-ZR3000

Answer (score 8):

### Leica

- Digital-Modul-R
- M8
- M9
- M (Typ 240)
- M Monochrom
- M Monochrom (Typ 246)
- M-E
- M-P
- M10
- Q (Typ 116)
- S2
- S
- S-E (Typ 006)
- S (Typ 007)
- SL (Typ 601)
- X1
- X2
- X Vario (Typ 107)
- X (Typ 113)
- X-U (Typ 113)
- X-E (Typ 102)

Comment: That's not true of the D-Lux models, which obviously use Panasonic's raw format.

Answer (score 3):

### Samsung

- GX-10
- GX-20
- Pro 815

(All models are discontinued.)

Answer (score 0):

### LG

Most of their flagship phones, e.g.:

- G4
- G5
- G6
- G7
- V10
- V20
- V30

Answer (score 0):

I know that I should not provide link-only answers, but this Wikipedia article may be helpful, specifically if it's kept up to date:

[Section "Summary of products that support DNG in some way" from "Digital Negative. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Negative#Summary_of_products_that_support_DNG_in_some_way), more specifically for the question:
["Digital cameras and related software" from "Digital Negative. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Negative#Digital_cameras_and_related_software)